# Javascript Recursive Variable

Tags: javascript, variables, recursion

I am trying to test out a bubble tree diagramming set of scripts. In the examples, they provide a very simple example and then examples built out of recursive code. I need to be able to add children to the children tag in the data variable. I know it is simple but can not figure it out. The instructions say:

The child nodes then are (recursivly) inserted within the children array.

rootNode = {
    label: "Total budget",
    amount: 1000000,
    children: [{
        label: "Health",
        amount: 650000
    }, {
        label: "Government",
        amount: 350000
    }]
}

Here is the example code from the sample, I want to add a child to the 'third child' element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        var data = {
            label: 'Total',
            amount: 100,
            color: '#0066bb',  // color for root node, will be inherited by children
            children: [
                { label: 'First child', amount: 30 },
                { label: 'Second child', amount: 40 },
                { label: 'Third child', amount: 30, color: '#ff3300' }
            ]
        };

        new BubbleTree({
            data: data,
            container: '.bubbletree'
        });
    });

</script>
```

here is the git hub wiki: https://github.com/okfn/bubbletree/wiki/Bubble-Tree-Documentation

Would love a simple point in the right direction.

------- OK added the push per the below, but it is putting it on the parent node not t he child node where I want it

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        var data = {
            label: 'Total',
            amount: 100,
            color: '#0066bb',  // color for root node, will be inherited by children
            children: [
                { label: 'First child', amount: 30 },
                { label: 'Second child', amount: 40 },
                { label: 'Third child', amount: 30, color: '#ff3300' }

            ]
        };

        data.children.push({ label: "Computation", amount: 10 });

        new BubbleTree({
            data: data,
            container: '.bubbletree'
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pure JavaScript that shows you the information you are seeking :)

```
 var rootNode = {
      label: "Total budget",
      amount: 1000000,
      children: [
           {
                label: "Health",
                amount: 650000
           }, {
                label: "Government",
                amount: 350000
           }
      ]
 }

 rootNode.children.push({ label: "Computation", amount: "Smomputation" });

 rootNode.children.push({ label: "Not", amount: "Too bad" });

 console.log(rootNode);
```

push() adds to the end of an array. This is super critical stuff for you to understand in JS.

I highly recommend practicing with the following things until you master them:

- pop(); https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop?v=control
- push(); https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=control
- shift(); https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift?v=control
- unshift(); https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift?v=control
- splice(); https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?v=control
- slice(); https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?v=control
- indexOf(); https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?v=control

Your time will be extremely well spent because these are the foundations of working with collections of data.

I recommend learning a few examples of each and write them all out from memory once or twice a day for the next week.

If you see {}, it's probably an object. If you see [], it's probably an array. After that, you know which tools you have at your disposal. In your example, you see the children are wrapped in [], so adding another involves pop(); :)

Equally important are `for loops` because they are useful in examples like the one you are posting. Add this to the bottom of the example I gave above:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < rootNode.children.length; i++) {
     if (rootNode.children[i].label === "Computation") {
       console.log("Child found: " + rootNode.children[i].label + " (Hey, thats me) - Amount: " + rootNode.children[i].amount);
     } else {
       console.log("Child found: " + rootNode.children[i].label + " - Amount: " + rootNode.children[i].amount);
     }
 }
```

You should become comfortable with `for loops`, `while loops`, and `forEach();`

Your JavaScripting will accelerate significantly once you become comfortable with this stuff. Have fun, this practice you are doing now is the gateway to crazy Backend API development work, getting and setting documents out of databases (especially NoSQL type and graph databases), and HTTP requests/responses.

Here is the answer you're looking for:

```
 var data = {
             label: 'Total',
             amount: 100,
             color: '#0066bb',  // color for root node, will be inherited by children
             children: [
                 { label: 'First child', amount: 30 },
                 { label: 'Second child', amount: 40 },
                 { label: 'Third child', amount: 30, color: '#ff3300' }
             ]
 };

 data.children[2].rodent = "meat";
 data.children[2].steven = { tractor: "driver", yolo: true };
 data.children[2].seagull = [1,2,3];

 console.log("JSON object version");
 console.log("===================");
 console.log(data);
 console.log("JSON string version");
 console.log("===================");
 console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: You should not be doing jQuery until you understand the basics of JavaScript, or else you will get confused by simple things. Go back to basics, master ES5, then once you understand flow control, arrays, objects, functions, conditionals, loops, operators, selecting and manipulating DOM elements, then try jQuery again.

You will learn double as fast.

Comment: Terrific thanks. I'm a PHP guy who every now and then has to deal with JS. Appreciate all the help!

Comment: OK, so now that I have looked at this, you CLEARLY are an expert and know all this stuff, but, how would I add the children to to the 'third child' element in the sample code? The wonderful example you gave me is for some other variable. I know it may be frustrating for you since you are so good at this, but an example for the 'third node' element will really help me..

Comment: I added your answer for you. Now I am late for work but at least we know the value of data.children[2].steven.yolo

Comment: Check out some tutorials related to dot notation and bracket notation, and working with JSON objects. My reply looks a bit weird, but your true issue was that you needed to use data.children[2] to identify the 3rd key which is an array of children objects. After that, you can use dot notation to mutate in new key/values since its an object. Your JavaScript and jQuery will become extremely more gooder if you practice these things. Trust me, I want to see you win :)

Comment: Thanks for the help you nailed it! I really don't have interest in javascript or jquery I am a php guy, but these to come up from time to time. I typically just buy or find an already written framework, like here, and plug the data in.. very cool thaqnk you for your help.